# How do I root my HTC Hero?

Tags: htc-hero, rooting

I'm tired of waiting for my Android 2.1 update to arrive, so I've decided to root my HTC Hero.

Any direction as to how I should do this?

*Note: I actually have a T-Mobile branded version, so I do need some workaround because it doesn't let itself be unlocked as easily as vanilla HTC Heros.*

Comment: There are good tutorials for that over at [RootzWiki](http://rootzwiki.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here:

http://rootmydroid.co.uk/guides/hero/howto-root-your-htc-hero/

Like you, I got fed up with waiting for OTA upgrade from Orange. Using [VillainRom 12](http://www.villainrom.co.uk/wiki/index.php?title=VillainROM_12_Series), which is brilliant. No regrets!

Comment: Perhaps you could add a short summary of the steps to take in general. Note: I switched to ChocolatEclair, like it a bit better than VillainRom

Answer (score 3):

UniversalAndroot - Awesome tool that is EXTREMELY! easy. I used it for my Sprint HTC Hero all I did was download the .apk at the bottom of the post, put it on my sdcard. Ran it off my SDCard via Estrong File Explorer and it rooted my device perfectly. After it roots, run Rom Manager and install the ClockWorkMod Recovery Screen. After that, find the ROM you want to flash.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=747598

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to root mine with the [unrevoked](http://unrevoked.com/) tool. (Sprint HTC Hero w/2.1)

Answer (score 1):

The second half of the first post in [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=875351) tells you how you can root your current firmware.  Basically you just use z4root:

- Download z4root from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=833953
- Install and run z4root, click Permanent Root
- Let it run until it says it has completed
- Ensure you see Superuser in your app drawer

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I had been looking for a site with instructions for my version but for some reason didn't find that one!  I'll give it a try this weekend!