# Rooting HTC Hero GSM 2.1-update-1 (3.41.61.31)

Tags: rooting, htc-hero, rom

So I've been trying to root my HTC (Hero GSM 2.1-update-1 (3.41.61.31), originally Orange Spain, but unlocked by code) for few hours now, haven't managed yet.
All the articles I've found about rooting this phone seems to be quite old and none seem to be more recent than the latest OTA update they've sent.

Even the latest version of Androot (1.6.2 beta 5) doesn't seem to work; I keep getting a `Failed ! No ~~~ Fu goo ~~~` seemingly clueless error.

Found some more hardcore ways to do it, but then again, all of them quite old and no one confirming if for the current version - I don't want to end up with an expensive paperweight :(

I want to root it in order to install the latest Froyo ROM (Oh, and if anyone have serious reason for opposing to the villainrom 1.7, I'd appreciate a headsup)

Please, could anyone refer me to the definite how-to-root-this-thing?

cheers mates,

f.

Comment: See also: [How do I root my HTC Hero?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/456/16575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like no one has cracked the latest version of your firmware to allow for root access so you will have to downgrade to an earlier version of your stock ROM.  You may have already seen all this in your travels but if not, it may help.

***Warning, this is by no means a definitive guide, but it's my best shot:***

**Downgrade your firmware:**

- Here is an [old guide on how to downgrade](http://theunlockr.com/2009/10/18/how-to-downgrade-your-htc-hero-so-it-can-be-rooted/), but it still should be relevant.
- Here are [old ROMs for your phone](http://www.htc.com/uk/SupportDownloadList.aspx?p_id=283&act=sd&cat=2).

**Root:**

This [guide over at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=645253&highlight=root) is pretty comprehensive.  It was last updated in August, but it looks like it was edited just two weeks ago so it should still be good info.  I'd read through the thread and to see how it's been working for people.  There may actually be more relevant instructions later on in the thread.

**Again, I have no idea if this will work, so proceed at your own risk.**

Comment: Thanks mate. That's what I've been working into. Let's see if it works. Quite a hassle actually the whole downgrade thing :(